# How can I get Unity to tell me the battery status of my OS X laptop?

Tags: unity, macos

How do I get battery status on an OS X laptop in Unity?

This is un-Googlable: I keep finding either mobile stuff (iOS or Android) or people complaining about laptop battery life.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Unity exposes this in a platform-agnostic fashion. You will have to call down to the lower level APIs.

There are two ways I can think of offhand to get this. The first is to use the `Process` class to execute the [OS X `pmset` tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html) and parse the output. `pmset -g batt` displays battery status to stdout, which you can parse for what you need.

The other is to use platform invoke [to call the IOPowerSources functions directly](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOPowerSources_header_reference/#//apple_ref/c/func/IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo). You'll need three functions at least (`IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo`, `IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList` and `IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription`), so it may be easier to write a small library that calls them in C and exposes a single entry point for you to invoke. I seem to recall there being restrictions on P/Invoke in the free version of Unity in the past, so this may not be an option for you if that still applies.

[This thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272552/battery-status-in-osx) also discusses the issue, although it does not address anything Unity specific.

Comment: by "platform invoke" do you mean something other than writing a plugin? I know how to write a simple iOS plugin for stuff like this, but I'd be curious if there's an even easier approach.

Comment: @jhocking Yeah, using [DllExport("whateverLibraryIsCalled.so")] on a public static extern function with a matching signature to that of the IOPowerSource function you want.

Comment: huh I didn't know you could do that. something new every day!